# Remove content inside script that comes after build angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

In Angular 8, I used angular universal tool.
In that, after build is generated with help of **npm run build** command line.
It gives me script with id called "serverApp-state".
The id can be change from app.server.module.ts.
here is code where I found id of script.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

After **npm run buid** , I found this code at the end of build file home page in view source. What I need is to **remove content** inside script.

[image]

Comment: I believe that is used for server side rendering why you want to remove that?

Comment: @Niladri there are lots of code APIs in content so It gives me error in SEO side. so I need to remove content inside that script

Comment: You can find the element by id and remove it's content.

Comment: @vrajesh any update on this?

Comment: @VenkaTeshuser5397700 i have not found any solution but I change whole project structure with another (where script is there but no code inside script) and remain script but remove json data inside script.

Comment: could you tell me the approach pls @vrajesh